# Powershell Cannot find type [System.Data.DataTable]

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to query a Microsoft SQL Server via PowerShell.  I have version 4 installed.

I'm attempting to connect to a Microsoft SQL server database. I've done this before on a different computer.  The first line of the script that worked before is.

```
$records = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
```

This generates this error

> Error: New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Data.DataTable]: verify
>   that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I think I need something installed which makes the `System.Data.DataTable` available but I've not been able to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the [SMO objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245202.aspx) in order to run queries against SQL Server.  As recommended in that article though, it's easier to [import the SQLPS module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286.aspx).